# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputRadioGroup` does not support the type xxx

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to use radio group in blazor so after implementing edit form and select one of the radio button I got this error :

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputRadioGroup`1[EGameCafe.SPA.Models.GameModel] does not support the type 'EGameCafe.SPA.Models.GameModel'.

here is my edit form :

```
<EditForm Model="ViewModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleCreateGroup">

            @if (ViewModel.Games.List.Any())
            {
                <InputRadioGroup Name="GameSelect" @bind-Value="Gamemodelsample">
                    @foreach (var game in ViewModel.Games.List)
                        {
                        <InputRadio Value="game" />
                        @game.GameName
                        <br />
                        }
                </InputRadioGroup>
            }

</EditForm>

@code{
        public GameModel GameModelSample { get; set; } = new();
}
```

and GameModel is :

```
 public class GameModel
{
        public string GameId { get; set; }
        public string GameName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InputRadioGroup, like other Blazor components, supports only a limited amount of types like `String` or `Int32`. You had the right idea, but unfortunately, you run into a kind of limitation of Blazor.

You could try to create a wrapper field.

```
   private String _selectedGameId = "<Your Default Id>";

    public String SelectedGameId
    {
        get => _selectedGameId;
        set
        {
            _selectedGameId = value;
            // Set the property of the ViewModel used in your Model Property of the EditContext or any other property/field 
            ViewModel.SelectedGame = ViewModel.Games.List?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GameId == value);
        }
    }
```

Use the property `SelectedGameId` as the bind value of the InputRadioGroup component.

```
<InputRadioGroup Name="GameSelect" @bind-Value="SelectedGameId" >
            @foreach (var game in ViewModel.Games.List)
            {
                <InputRadio Value="game.GameId" />
                @game.GameName
                <br />
            }
</InputRadioGroup>
```

As an alternative, you can create a custom component that inheriting from `InputRadioGroup`  to create a kind of `GameBasedInputRadioGroup`. If you are interested I can post a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your code `@bind-Value="Gamemodelsample"`,you are trying to bind `GameName`(string) to `Gamemodelsaple`(object), which will cause type mismatch problems.

You only need to modify your code to:

```
@bind-Value="GameModelSample.GameName"
```